# PowerPoint Slideshow Viewer Online

Tags: javascript, html, ms-office, powerpoint, aspose

I'm looking for a service online that would allow me to run a PowerPoint Slideshow (along with slide transitions and animations).

As we know we have Office Online available for this purpose and also this* [url](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=abc.com) can help you achieve slideshow capabilities.

But these options don't give much control to developers to develop some experiences based on slideshow capabilities they provide. So I'm looking for alternatives though it doesn't seems there is anything like thing as per research I did so far.

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

* https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=abc.com

PS. We have different parser/extractor libraries for PPTX but nothing is there that allows view of PPTX/Slideshow over the html web-page.

Comment: Microsoft has that locked up. You'll have better luck looking for open-source presentation libraries. Here's an article to get your research started, they mention Reveal.js, about which I've heard good things: https://opensource.com/business/16/9/alternatives-powerpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For future reference**

Just dumping my thoughts for future reference. As of now, no solution or workaround is possible other than Office Online itself as mentioned in Question above.

[Aspose](https://www.aspose.com/) is planning to provide support to similar subject requirements in future. So hopefully once the new version of the library is out, we will be able to achieve the desired behavior.

[Aspose Reference Ticket](https://forum.aspose.com/t/convert-ppt-to-html-with-animation/8668).

Answer (score 0):

Could you just build it on the Desktop version of PowerPoint and drop it into OneDrive folder? As far as i can tell, if you drop it into OneDrive, it'll run as-is in online via PowerPoint 365.

Comment: thank you. Yes it will work the way you said. But I need more control. In other words, I need a user control or component that can be embedded to any html webpage.